# XCode library not found for -lPods-

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, app-store

I'm Publishing an app to Apple store and I got this error after clicking on product->archive

```
Library not found for -lPods-Kefan Optics
```

The app developed by Ionic 4 and Cordova

The error details:

```sh
Ld /Users/esham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kefan_Optics-bvddltavdgfpjtgrsrqnckhvxasw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Kefan\ Optics/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Kefan\ Optics.app/Kefan\ Optics normal arm64 (in target 'Kefan Optics' from project 'Kefan Optics')
    cd /Volumes/Partion-2/Projects/kefan/platforms/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios11.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -L/Users/esham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kefan_Optics-bvddltavdgfpjtgrsrqnckhvxasw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Kefan\ Optics/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/esham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kefan_Optics-bvddltavdgfpjtgrsrqnckhvxasw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Kefan\ Optics/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Volumes/Partion-2/Projects/kefan/platforms/ios/Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework -filelist /Users/esham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kefan_Optics-bvddltavdgfpjtgrsrqnckhvxasw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Kefan\ Optics/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Kefan\ Optics.build/Release-iphoneos/Kefan\ Optics.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Kefan\ Optics.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/esham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kefan_Optics-bvddltavdgfpjtgrsrqnckhvxasw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Kefan\ Optics/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Kefan\ Optics.build/Release-iphoneos/Kefan\ Optics.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Kefan\ Optics_lto.o -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Applications/Kefan\ Optics.app/Kefan\ Optics -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -ObjC -framework CoreGraphics -framework OneSignal -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework UserNotifications -framework WebKit /Users/esham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kefan_Optics-bvddltavdgfpjtgrsrqnckhvxasw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Kefan\ Optics/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a -weak_framework WebKit -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreTelephony -lPods-Kefan\ Optics -framework CoreLocation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/esham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kefan_Optics-bvddltavdgfpjtgrsrqnckhvxasw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Kefan\ Optics/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Kefan\ Optics.build/Release-iphoneos/Kefan\ Optics.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Kefan\ Optics_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/esham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kefan_Optics-bvddltavdgfpjtgrsrqnckhvxasw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Kefan\ Optics/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Kefan\ Optics.app/Kefan\ Optics
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simply opening the xxx.xcworkspace instead of xxx.xcodeproj